# Is it possible to add JSON code to hide and show other rows based on column value?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I am using view formatting with JSON and wondering if its possible to add
button that can sort, hide and show other rows based on their column value, like only show items in toys department store and hide other departments, sports, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can create links to your view with filter query strings. Here's an example of how to do that with a multi-choice field:

```
{
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "=join(@currentField,', ')",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "=@currentWeb + '/lists/Allies/Orderable.aspx?FilterFields1=Drinks&FilterOp1=Eq&FilterValues1=' + join(@currentField, '%3B%23')"
  }
}
```

In the example above, the list name is `Allies`, the view is `Orderable.aspx`, and the internal column name is `Drinks` all of which are hardcoded in the format as there isn't yet a way to pull this information from context.

You can do the same with sorting by using additional query strings. For example adding `sortField=PhoneNumber&isAscending=true` would sort the view by the column with the internal name of `PhoneNumber`.

The easiest way to make sure you're getting these query string values right, is to apply filters and/or sorts to your view and note the query strings applied in the URL. Then build your links using those and plug in dynamic values (from the current list item) as needed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,if we want to hide an item in list,we need to add Conditional class to list, but there is no original class that can hide the item.
All classes we can use:
[image]
Of course,we could use custom class,then we need to inject our custom css through spfx.
https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is **not possible** using JSON view formatting as you cannot get the column values from another rows/list items in JSON code.

You can only access the column values from the same list item/row like `[$AnotherColumnFromSameRow]`.

Where `AnotherColumnFromSameRow` is internal name another column from same list item/row. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Official documentation**: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)