# SP view formatting row display

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

Is there any solution to hide specific row in the list using JSON for view formatting.

I want to display only rows that match the terms of the current user and hide others.

In Column formatting I can do this with "display", is it possible to use this in view formatting?

Thanks a lot for the answers!

Comment: Do you want to hide the rows based on user permissions or based on the column/field in your list?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done with the out-of-box JSON row formatting functionality. You might need to inject custom classes using SPFx and then be able to do it.

This question has already been answered in this forum [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/285952/is-it-possible-to-add-json-code-to-hide-and-show-other-rows-based-on-column-valu/285972#285972)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to filter the items with current user, you can try to use the filter settings in the view with the dynamic filter value [me]. It works for people picker column.

More information here:https://www.sharepointsapiens.com/list-filter-web-part/documentation/initially-filter-sharepoint-view-current-user/